# Powershell remote application(.cmd) deployment

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am beginner with PowerShell and struggling to get this around with the help from different sites, My requirement and scenario is

I have a windows server 2008(rktdepy) with PowerShell installed and I have packaged application with a `.cmd` file. When I click this `.cmd` file the application will be deployed.

The server name is `rktdepy` and I want to create a PowerShell script which will connect to other servers in the network (the server names should be picked up from a txt files) and install the application accessing the file remotely from  `rktdepy` server. The files are not supposed to be copied to any server and should not use psxec for security reason.

So far I have used invoke and mapping the network drive but still I have issues

```
$Comsession = Get-content c:\adminfiles\scripts\deploy.txt | new-pssession -throttlelimit 50
Invoke-command -computername RKTDEPLY54 -scriptblock { (new-object -comobject wscript.network).mapnetworkdrive("R:", "\\rktdepy\deploy", $true) }
Invoke-command -session $comsession -scriptblock {"CMD /C r:\QR_DEPLOY.CMD"}
```

The above script throws error,

I dont want to use any password in the script and it should fetch the current logged in user password from `rktdepy` server. I is ok if the scripts prompts for a user name and password which will have admin access to all servers.

Comment: What error is being thrown? You can't say that an error is thrown and then make people guess at it.

Comment: Sorry i missed to mention this, I had previous error related to limited session which i got it sorted out by increasing the session. BUt the problem is that i dont receive any error message and when i check login into the server, i couldnt see the drives mapped until i logoff and log back in. Moreover for testing purpose i just mentioned to create a folder in .cmd but i dont see any folder been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have testing the following on my machine and it is working so far.  There is also another method you can try out listed below.

**Method1:**
1. I have txt file with a list of computers named `allcomputers.txt`. It contains name of machines on each line.

```
Machine10  
Machine20  
Machine30  
Machine40
```

1. The deployment script (`mydeploytest.ps1`) which accepts Computername, Username and Password as input and creates a new PSSession and then invokes command.

   param(
   [string]$ComputerName,
   [string]$User,
   [string]$pass
   )
   Get-PSSEssion | Remove-PSSession
   $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
   Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
   param(
   [string]$ComputerName,
   [string]$Username,
   [string]$Password
   )
       $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
       $net.MapNetworkDrive("U:", "\\RKTDEPY\deploy", $false, $Username, $Password)
       Invoke-Expression "CMD /C U:\deploy.cmd"
       $net.RemoveNetworkDrive("U:")
   } -args $ComputerName,$User,$pass
   Get-PSSEssion | Remove-PSSession
2. Powershell commandline oneline to accomplish deployment task.

PS C:> Get-Content C:\scripts\allcomputers.txt | Foreach { C:\scripts\mydeploytest.ps1 $_ "yourserviceaccount" "password"}

**Method2:**
The help method for Invoke-Command has an example on how to solve the doublehop issue stevals is mentioning in the answer.

```
PS C:\> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Delegate Server02
 PS C:\>Connect-WSMan Server02
 PS C:\>Set-Item WSMan:\Server02*\Service\Auth\CredSSP -Value $true
 PS C:\>$s = New-PSSession Server02
 PS C:\>Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Get-Item \\Net03\Scripts\LogFiles.ps1} -Authentication CredSSP
 -Credential Domain01\Admin01
```

I think with little modification to method 2 you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable inputs and extremely sorry for the delay as i was long leave... I tried the script and it works fabulously if i have to run a normal batch file with creating folders or files.... but it was my mistake i missed to mention this earlier... the script should execute a .cmd file rather than .bat file. The .cmd file has got its own scripts which uses cscript also.. please advice

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it solved your problem and ask another question related to it.

Comment: I have asked as a separate question, can you please kindly help me with that

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are dealing with a couple problems.  One is that the session where you map the drive is gone when you run the next Invoke-Command that uses the mapped drive.  You could move that into the same script block to fix a problem like that.  The second one is a "second hop" issue.  See a resource like Don Jones' Secrets of PowerShell Remoting free ebook on http://powershell.org/wp/books.
Steve